# How to specify text view when I use include in my layout xml file

Tags: android

I have a layout xml file which includes another smaller xml file.

```
<include layout="@layout/text" android:id="@+id/test1"/>
<include layout="@layout/text" android:id="@+id/test2"/>
```

where my text.xml is

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
</merge>
```

My question is how can I specify different text view in my text view in test1 and test2 in my layout xml file? Or I have to do that in my java code?

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to approach an application in the same way. Did you ever find out if this is possible? I would expect that android would have a way to pass a resource through the include to the merged view.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you have to do that in java code. My experience of xml is that it is 100% static.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821976/2543138.  Yes, it can be done in xml, you just have get the id of the include first in the code and then get the text element.