# Include tag and dataBinding

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-databinding

I want to use one of my layouts multiple times in the same view using `include`. Let's say I have a `custom.xml` including some `TextView`s.

`custom.xml`:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have included this layout multiple times in `parent.xml`:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/custom"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"/>

    <include layout="@layout/custom"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to bind my data models to this layout, but the problem is that I don't know how to bind two different data models to `layout1` and `layout2` since both of them are refrenced from one layout which is `custom.xml`. As far as I know I can add this tag in my xml layout:

```
    <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.myproject.model.User"/>
   </data>
```

But I need to bind two different data models to `custom.xml`.

My question is how to have an included layout multiple times in one view and passing different data to them using Data Binding? something like passing data to the layout but not statically binding a model to an xml.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355122/how-to-include-a-layout-twice-in-android) question which is exactly had the same problem But since Data Binding is released in newer versions of android I am seeking a way to solve the same issue using Data Binding. Here is the part of that question that I have quoted for clarification:

> For instance, I have a carefully crafted layout that I want to display
>   three times in my view. Every of those instances would need different
>   values. Since the `include` is basically a take that XML and paste it
>   here, I'd need something more powerful.

Comment: If the layouts are same, and only the data is changing, why dont you consider to using a custom recycleView ?

Comment: because I want to pass two different data models for example one is User and another is Address but both models are using the same layout to show their data

Comment: @MiladFaridnia hey Gentleman can u help me with given link question comment?         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554796/rotate-marker-and-move-animation-on-map-like-uber-android/39569076

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can pass that from `parent.xml`

```
<include layout="@layout/custom"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    app:user="@{object of user1`}"/>

<include layout="@layout/custom"
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    app:user="@{object of user2`}"/>
```

Here you need to pass `User` object from `parent.xml`

Make sure you have `<data>` in custom.xml

```
<data>
   <variable name="user" type="com.myproject.model.User"/>
</data>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag) is detailed answer related to this, refer it

Comment: Thanks for your answer It's so close to the final answer but is it possible to pass two kinds of models (for example one is User and another is Address) to custom.xml ?

Comment: yes, in that case you need to take two variables in `custom.xml`

Comment: something like this ?
<data>
   <variable name="user" type="com.myproject.model.User"/>   <variable name="address" type="com.myproject.model.Address"/>
</data>

Comment: first I was wondering why this should work because I havn't defined a binding for `app:user`.
BUT it works like a charm! thanks

Comment: what if I want to pass in two paramter, it will not work

Comment: You can pass 2 parameters.

Comment: It has to be "bind:user" instead of "app:user" https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes

Answer (score 18):

We know how to use the POJO name and its type on the XML which we are using in `setContentView()` as a parent view. We should focus on the `include` tag if we are including any layouts from resource as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="exapmpe.model.User" />
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            bind:user="@{user}" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Here we've use the **`bind`** attribute to pass the object to show the detailed info on the content screen. Please make sure the **object name should be same** in both places like `bind:user="@{user}`. The `content_main.xml` should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="exapmpe.model.User" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_main" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.firstName + user.lastName}" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the included layout isn't being thought of as a data-bound layout, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag) to undertstand how to solve it

Comment: Thanks for your useful link but I think you must include more description in your answer

Answer (score 2):

1> In the Main layout screen where you use include tag added **xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** This code is under the layout tag. For your reference check the screenshot.

point 1

[image: reference screenshort]

2> Now under your include tag add bind:includeLayoutViewModel="@{viewModel}" (In this case add your ViewModel name which you declare)For more check out the screenshot

For point 2

[image: reference screenshot]

3> Now in your included layout screen call ViewModel here for reference check the below screenshot (In screenshots there is TestViewModel behalf of this you mention your view model which is you declare in your main layout screen)

For point 3 [image: screenshot]