# Identify view inside an include

Tags: android, layout, view

I have this include

[image]

I have to "include" this "include" two times,  in the same layout.

[image]

How can I get the TextView inside RL1?
I thought I could do this:

```
RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL1);
TextView textView = (TextView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```

but this way seems that I get the same Instance of the TextView, both from RL1 and RL2.

This is the full layout:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout          
        android:id="@+id/RL1">
        <include layout="@layout/game_area"/>
    </RelativeLayout>   


    <RelativeLayout         
        android:id="@+id/RL2">
        <include layout="@layout/game_area"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: does the other `include` has a different `@+id`?

Comment: add `@+id` to the `include` tag

Comment: Excuse me. There was another error. The way I did works.
Thank you and sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 0):

When you search by id you always find the first items, so the second widgets are hidden.

However, it can be solved

```
<include> -- id1
-- stuff
</include>
<include> -- id2
-- stuff
</include>
```

So we can find the subelements, by first looking up id2 / id1.

```
View include_1 = findViewById(R.id.id1); 
View include_2 = findViewById(R.id.id2);
```

and finally

```
include_2.findViewById(R.id.elementx );
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821976/5707364

Comment: Excuse me. There was another error. The way I did works. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: As per your question, you can get TextView inside RL1 by just doing this: <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RL2"> <include layout="@layout/game_area" android:id="@+id/id2"/> </RelativeLayout> and findViewById(R.id.id2).findViewById(R.id.textViewId );

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout>
    <include android:id="@+id/RL1" layout="@layout/game_area"/>
</RelativeLayout>   


<RelativeLayout>
    <include android:id="@+id/RL2" layout="@layout/game_area"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you shuold add `id` to the `include` tag

Comment: Excuse me. There was another error. The way I did works. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time :)